# How to set read only flag on streamed content from web server

Tags: php, asp.net, http, coldfusion, http-headers

Is there a way include or suggest a read only flag as part of a content-disposition: attachment; filename=document.doc or other http header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suspect not.  Typically, you don't have any control over the browser's local filesystem (as it should be) so you can't specify that a file is read-only, archive, hidden, etc.